# What is time(NULL) in C?

Tags: c, time

I learning about some basic C functions and have encountered `time(NULL)` in some manuals.

What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can pass in a pointer to a `time_t` object that `time` will fill up with the current time (and the return value is the same one that you pointed to). If you pass in `NULL`, it just ignores it and merely returns a new `time_t` object that represents the current time.

Answer (score 47):

The call to `time(NULL)` returns the current calendar time (seconds since Jan 1, 1970).  See [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/) for details.  Ordinarily, if you pass in a pointer to a `time_t` [variable](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time_t/), that pointer variable will point to the current time.

Comment: +1. Also for a variable `timer` of type `time_t`, `time(&timer);` is equivalent to `timer = time(NULL);`

Answer (score 39):

`time()` is a very, very old function.  It goes back to a day when the C language didn't even have type `long`.  Once upon a time, the only way to get something like a 32-bit type was to use an array of two `int`s — and that was when `int`s were 16 bits.

So you called

```
int now[2];
time(now);
```

and it filled the 32-bit time into `now[0]` and `now[1]`, 16 bits at a time.  (This explains why the other time-related functions, such as `localtime` and `ctime`, tend to accept their time arguments via pointers, too.)

Later on, [dmr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie) finished adding `long` to the compiler, so you could start saying

```
long now;
time(&now);
```

Later still, someone realized it'd be useful if `time()` went ahead and returned the value, rather than just filling it in via a pointer.  But — backwards compatibility is a wonderful thing — for the benefit of all the code that was still doing `time(&now)`, the `time()` function had to keep supporting the pointer argument.  Which is why — and this is why backwards compatibility is not always such a wonderful thing, after all — if you're using the return value, you still have to pass NULL as a pointer:

```
long now = time(NULL);
```

(Later still, of course, we started using `time_t` instead of plain `long` for times, so that, for example, it can be changed to a 64-bit type, dodging the [y2.038k problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).)

[P.S.  I'm not actually sure the change from `int [2]` to `long`, and the change to add the return value, happened at different times; they might have happened at the same time.  But note that when the time was represented as an array, it *had* to be filled in via a pointer, it couldn't be returned as a value, because of course C functions can't return arrays.]

Comment: The 2.4 Linux kernel had a bug with a 64 bit `time_t` where if you passed in a non NULL parameter that it would only fill in the lower 32 bits leaving the upper bits unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

The `time` function returns the current time (as a `time_t` value) in seconds since some point (on Unix systems, since midnight UTC January 1, 1970), and it takes one argument, a `time_t` pointer in which the time is stored.  Passing `NULL` as the argument causes `time` to return the time as a normal return value but not store it anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

`Time` : It returns the time elapsed in seconds since the epoch 1 Jan 1970

Comment: `time`, not `Time` -- and the seconds since 1970 thing is not specified by the C language (it's POSIX).

Answer (score 1):

You have to refer to the [documentation for ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/). `time` is a function that takes one parameter of type `time_t *` (a pointer to a `time_t` object) and assigns to it the current time. Instead of passing this pointer, you can also pass `NULL` and then use the returned time_t value instead.

Comment: The `ctime` referred to here is the C++ header `<ctime>`, which is similar to the C header `<time.h>`. (The question was about C, not C++.) There's also a function called `ctime`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a pointer to a `time_t` object that time will fill up with the current time (and the return value is the same one that you pointed to). If you pass in `NULL`, it just ignores it and merely returns a new `time_t` object that represents the current time.

`Nb:time(&timer);` is equivalent to `timer = time(NULL);`

Answer (score 0):

```
int main (void)
{   
    //print time in seconds from 1 Jan 1970 using c   
    float n = time(NULL);   
    printf("%.2f\n" , n);      
}
```

this prints 1481986944.00 (at this moment).

Comment: This answer is wrong because `time` returns `time_t`, and will lose precision when stored into `float`.