# How to get random numbers in a loop?

Tags: c

Attached is my code for my craps game. I get player wins 100% of the time because my rand() is calling the same numbers for all 1,000,000 games. I've seen so many people post about this same issue and everyone says to call srand one time only, but I guess I am not understanding what this means. This is my sixth week in C and it's starting to get really confusing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define numGames (1000000)
#define plrWinThrw (7, 11)
#define hseWinThrw (2, 3, 12)


int rollDice ();
int playGame ();


int main ()
{
  srand (time (NULL));
  int playerWins = 0;
  int houseWins = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < numGames; i++)
    {
      int result = playGame ();
      if (result == 1)
        {
          playerWins++;
        }
      else
        {
          houseWins++;
        }
    }

  float playerProb = (float) playerWins / numGames * 100;
  float houseProb = (float) houseWins / numGames * 100;

  printf ("Number of games won by the player: %d\n", playerWins);
  printf ("Number of games won by the house: %d\n", houseWins);
  printf ("Percent probability the player wins: %.1lf\n", playerProb);
  printf ("Percent probability the house wins: %.1lf\n", houseProb);

  return 0;
}

int rollDice ()
{
  int die1 = rand () % 6 + 1;
  int die2 = rand () % 6 + 1;
  int roll = die1 + die2;
  return roll;
}

int playGame ()
{
  int roll = rollDice ();

  if (roll = plrWinThrw)
    {
      return 1;
    }
  else if (roll = hseWinThrw)
    {
      return -1;
    }
  int point = roll;
  while (roll != point && roll != 7)
    {
      roll = rollDice ();
    }
  if (roll = point)
    {
      return 1;
    }
  return -1;
}
```

I've tried moving srand around as well as moving the rand() functions around. Nothing seems to solve my issue.

Comment: _"I've tried moving srand around..."_ - Don't. It's perfect where it is.

Comment: `if (roll = plrWinThrw)` Assignment... Use `==` to test for equality... (Several instances)

Comment: "I get player wins 100% of the time because my rand() is calling the same numbers for all 1,000,000 games" - in your own words, **why do you believe** that `rand` is giving you the same numbers each time, and **why do you believe** that this is why the player is winning 100% of the time? (Hint: both of those assumptions are incorrect.) Where the code says, for example, `if (roll = plrWinThrw)`, exactly what do you think this should mean, and why? (Hint: have you ever seen `==` in example code? What is the difference between `=` and `==`?)

Comment: Since my answer is getting downvoted I must assume that I misunderstood your question. **Treez81: What _is_ your question?**

Comment: another issue could be `(7, 11)`. I don't know what you think this does. C has no tuple-type, just the comma-operator. And I don't see how the comma-operator would help you here. What are you trying to express with the winThrows?

Comment: `#define plrWinThrw (7, 11)` and `if (roll == plrWinThrw)` (fixed...) What do you think this conditional is doing?

Comment: Increasing compiler warning level identifies all these issues: https://godbolt.org/z/P3cG1cK16

Comment: Hints: 1. learn the basics of the language from some book. 2. Learn how to use ther basics of your debugger, this will save you countless hours in the future. 3. Don't abuse macros, in your code they only make the code less readable.

Comment: You might consider turning those macros into functions: _e.g._ `int isPlayerWin(int x) { return x == 7 || x == 11; } int isHouseWin(int x) { return x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 12; }` Then you can just call the function: _e.g._ `if (isPlayerWin(roll)) ...`

Comment: Thanks everyone!  I'm an idiot and thanks for being nice about it.  I swear I stared at this code for so long and didn't see something so easy.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Treez81 staring at code doesn't help. Debugging code does.

Comment: Well, this was an experience. None of my previous answers have gotten this many downvotes - and I still think I answered "the question" in this case :-)

Comment: Hehe, controversial I guess. I didn't vote at all because I felt nobody really answered the intended question which is _"how to make my broken program not broken"_. All the juice was in the comments. The `srand` thing was a XY Problem decoy. The absence of any form of debugging led to the false assumption that `srand` is at fault. So I would guess that providing an answer addressing only that thing is always gonna be risky! To me it doesn't meet the criteria for downvoting, which is _"this answer is not useful"_. It was useful, although perhaps (subjectively) better suited to being a comment.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Your answer was a correct answer to the literal question, but not helpful to the OP, who asked the wrong question to fix his problem. I think this question perfectly demonstrates the two ways of viewing at answering as "helping the OP" vs "contributing to a QA-style-wikipedia". Ideally, an answer should be both I think, and none of the three answers do both. I don't think any answer could do both here.

Comment: @julaine  _"Your answer was a correct answer to the literal question, but not helpful to the OP, who asked the wrong question to fix his problem."_ - Thank you very much! Perhaps I missed the target this time, but I think OP now knows what it means to call `srand` and why one should do it only once - so, in that respect, I think I helped.

Comment: @paddy _"It was useful, although perhaps (subjectively) better suited to being a comment"_ - Thank you too! Perhaps I should have put it in with my first comment - but I felt it best to make a comment only about where to put `srand` and to provide an actual answer to what calling it means. Oh well ... :-)

Comment: @Treez81, Tip: the  most important lesson here is [enable all warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77140504/how-to-get-random-numbers-in-a-loop#comment135990709_77140504).

Answer (score 2):

You use the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==` in the if statements.

When you write `if (roll = plrWinThrw)` it assigns `plrWinThrw` to `roll` instead of comparing `roll` to `plrWinThrw`. To compare them properly you need to write `if (roll == plrWinThrw)`

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not use the answer section to explain typos, or questions where OP has not done any proper debugging work and is thus completely off base about what the problem is. Such questions should be closed, and not answered.

Answer (score 0):

You use random numbers correctly - calling srand once, with a seed, and after that calling rand.

Your issue seem to be your if-statements, they do not do what you think they do: **you are confusing assignment (`=`) and comparison (`==`)**. `x=1` is an assignment. It makes it so that `x` holds the value `1` and the statement evaluates to `1` (which counts as `true` if used in an if-statement). It does not matter what the previous value of `x` was!
On the other hand `x==1` does not change the value of `x`. It returns a truethy value if `x` holds the value `1`. This is what you normally want to use in an if-statement.

While this was an easy-to-make mistake, maybe even a typo, there is a systematic way to prevent this kind of bug: **Use compiler warnings**, they tell you about this sort of misleading code. On gcc/clang the `-Wall`-option does the trick, other compilers have equivalent options.

Answer (score -3):

> I've seen so many people post about this same issue and everyone says to call `srand` one time only, but I guess I am not understanding what this means.

The `s` in `srand` stands for `seed`. It's the initial value you give to the *pseudo random number generator*. It is its starting point so to speak.

It's *pseudo* because it's not really random at all. `rand` generates a number sequence number that will be *exactly* the same every time you give it the same seed (in the particular version of the library you're using - the actual forumla used in `rand` is not standardized).

Comment: Ok, how is this not helpful/accurate?

Comment: (I did not downvote this) - The question asker calls `srand(time(NULL))` which seeds the prng differently every time. So the random sequence will be different each time the program is started. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550269/what-is-timenull-in-c

Comment: @julaine I tried to answer what looked like "the question" to me. Regarding your statement: _"which seeds the prng differently every time"_ - That's true except in those cases where you start 10000000000 instances of the same program during the same second.

Comment: "Ok, how is this not helpful/accurate?" Because it attempts to answer a question that does not meet the site standards. If OP is asking what it means to call srand once, and has code that calls srand once, then that is clearly not the real question. A cursory examination of the code shows that it's full of typos of `=` where `==` should be used instead; and a cursory examination of the phrasing of the question shows that it's a blatant XY problem (OP wrongly assumes about the `rand` results without having properly checked them, and wrongly blames them for the wrong result).

Comment: Please keep in mind that answers to unsuitable questions [interfere with automatic cleanup of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions), putting increased demand on manual efforts.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for letting me know. I don't see what I perceived as "the question" as off topic though. I read the text and saw only one question in it and didn't really need to go into codereview mode to answer it.

Comment: "I read the text and saw only one question in it and didn't really need to go into codereview mode to answer it." This interpretation makes sense, but in this case a) the question is a duplicate (there are almost 400,000 questions in the [c] tag; surely at least one of them is a highly-voted one that explains the basics of how `srand` works?) and b) the entire code should be edited out as irrelevant.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel a) You are most probably correct but I don't have one on my personal dupe-list.  b) Agree 100%.

Comment: I think the post has been downvoted because it doesn't answer the question. There are several problems in the OP's code, but there is no incorrect usage of `srand` and `rand` .

Comment: @Jabberwocky I think you are correct in that those who downvoted didn't see "the question" the way I did it - and I'm outnumbered for sure :-) I actually _did_ try to answer the only question I saw in the original post.

Comment: @TedLyngmo hmmn. I don't see any `srand/rand` problems in the revision history either...

Comment: @Jabberwocky There are no actual question marks in "the question" which makes it into an interpretation issue. I see what I put as a heading in my answer as a question. OP doesn't understand what it means, so I answered that.